# CMD, Console, MS-DOS e termos relacionados

Tags: bash, shell, cmd, terminal, terminologia

Bom, deu uma embaraçada em todos os conceitos que vou listar abaixo, e gostaria que fosse apresentado a definição destes termos, talvez alguns sejam sinônimos de outros e outros sejam totalmente diferentes.

- SHELL
- BASH
- Terminal
- Console
- Prompt de Comandos
- MS-DOS
- DOS
- CMD

Algo breve, apenas para detectarmos o que é um e o que é outro na hora de ler ou ouvir falar destes termos.

Ps: seria isso um tópico muito amplo? Porquê para mim esses termos só vem na cabeça uma janela preta pronta para receber dados e processá-los.

Comment: Faltou só o Powershell :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell) significa "interpretador de comandos".

O [Bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)) é um tipo de shell do Unix/Linux, que contém sua própria sintaxe de comandos.

O [Cmd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe) é o interpretador de comandos dos Windows modernos (CMD.EXE). Ou seja, ele é um tipo de Shell. No Windows 95, 98 e Me ele se chamava COMMAND.COM.

[DOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOS) significa "Sistema operacional de disco". Basicamente é um sistema operacional que opera através de linha de comando de um Shell.

O [MS-DOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MS-DOS) é o Sistema Operacional de Disco desenvolvido pela Microsoft (MS). Nem todos os sistemas operacionais DOS são o MS-DOS da Microsoft (embora este seja o mais famoso e o que mais foi usado), pois existe/existiu também outros como o [AmigaDOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AmigaDOS), o [FreeDOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeDOS) e o [IBM PC DOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_PC_DOS), entre outros.

O [Console](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_console) é uma interface em modo texto utilizada para o usuário ler e digitar comandos.

O [Terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_terminal) é o dispositivo (computador físico) que você utiliza para visualizar ou digitar comandos. Mas ele não necessariamente é físico, pois pode ser emulado também, e neste caso provavelmente o Terminal será uma Janela ou uma Aplicação rodando.

O [Prompt de comandos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface#Command_prompt) é a parte do texto que aparece no Console pedindo para o usuário digitar uma linha de comando. Isso pode ser o `C:\>` que aparece no Cmd ou no DOS ou pode ser o `user@host: work_dir $` que aparece no Bash.

Ou seja, basicamente você vai no seu Terminal e abre o Console. Lá você pode ver o prompt de comando e informar ao Shell o que você quer fazer através de uma linha de comando a ser digitada. Este Shell, pode ser o Bash do Unix/Linux ou o Cmd do Windows, ou o Shell do DOS ou talvez seja alguma outra coisa. Se for o Shell do DOS, talvez este DOS seja o MS-DOS.