# Qual é a diferença entre & e && em SHELL?

Tags: shell

Estou usando o Terminal do `Ubuntu`.

Aprendi um determinado comando para poder liberar a memória, que é :

```
free & sync
```

Em outro caso, aprendi algo como

```
nohup &&
```

Afinal de contas, como são chamadas esses dois operadores  (`&` e `&&`) e quais são as diferenças entre eles?

Comment: Me corrigam se necessário! não sei a diferença entre terminal, shell e bash

Comment: Só uma referencia para aprendizagem, que eu estou usando e pode ser util, https://www.codecademy.com/pt/courses/learn-the-command-line

Comment: Seria legal dar uma olhada nessa resposta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/72969/cmd-console-ms-dos-e-termos-relacionados

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O operador `&` (Ampersand) é usado para colocar o comando anterior em *background* e, se houver um comando posterior, ele será executado independente do resultado do comando anterior:

```
free & sync
```

Quando este operador é usado ao final de um comando em um terminal no Linux, significa que você quer executar aquele comando e já liberar o terminal para novos comandos, sem aguardar o resultado do último comando:

```
wget http://pt.stackoverflow.com &
```

O operador `&&` (AND) é usado para que o próximo comando só seja executado se o comando anterior tiver sido executado com sucesso (`exit status` igual a 0):

```
mkdir pasta && cd pasta
```

Mais detalhes você encontra [aqui](http://www.tecmint.com/chaining-operators-in-linux-with-practical-examples/).

Comment: Muito esclarecedor. Obrigado, amigo!

Comment: Saída 0 significa que foi executado com sucesso. Qualquer outro valor significa erro.

Comment: @TNT corrigi aqui, obrigado