# CMD, PowerShell, Bash - Qual a diferença?

Tags: linux, windows, bash, cmd, powershell

Existe diferenças entre eles, quais?

Falo do Bash do Ubuntu.

Tenho a curiosidade porque pra mim eles parecem fazer a mesma coisa!

Comment: Veja esses links: [CMD, Console, MS-DOS e termos relacionados](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/72969/cmd-console-ms-dos-e-termos-relacionados?rq=1), [Qual a diferença de /bin/bash e /usr/bin/env bash?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/143822/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-de-bin-bash-e-usr-bin-env-bash?rq=1)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Essencialmente fazem mesmo, todos são utilitários de administração de sistemas para processar comandos iniciados a partir de uma interface com usuário baseado em texto (console). Ele é usado para chamar outros utilitários, iniciar processos e automatizar procedimentos através de uma linguagem de *script*. A abordagem e capacidade de cada um diferem.

[Bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)) é o mais conhecido utilitário deste tipo usado em sistemas POSIX (Linux, BSD, incluindo MacOS, etc. - não é específico de Ubuntu). Ele está disponível opcionalmente no Windows 10 à partir da atualização de 2016. Quando está usando Linux não tem disponível as duas opções abaixo, então a comparação não é muito necessária. Seria mais interessante uma comparação com processadores de comandos disponíveis no Linux.

[image: Bash no Windows]

[CMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe), também conhecido como *command prompt*, é o utilitário do Windows. Ele é simples e funciona, mas deixa a desejar para tarefas mais sofisticadas.

[PowerShell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell) é uma nova ferramenta disponível no Windows e mais recentemente no Linux e MacOS extremamente mais poderosa, flexível e extensível ([*cmdlet*](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/cmdlet-overview?view=powershell-7&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397)). Utiliza uma linguagem de programação e infraestrutura baseada no .NET (Core nas versões mais novas). Foi desenvolvido baseado nas experiências dos diversos processadores de *script* para sistemas operacionais anteriormente usados, entre eles, os dois acima. Ele veio para acabar com a ideia de que tudo no Windows é melhor fazer pela GUI. Ele é bastante consistente e mais simples de usar, mesmo sendo muito mais poderoso. Ele é um pouco mais voltado para administradores com boa capacidade de programação. Agora funciona em outros sistemas operacionais como o Linux.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Other/Conceptual.md).