# Como executar um script sem me preocupar com caracteres especiais?

Tags: windows, script, batch, diretório

Fiz um batch para windows para instalar alguns programas e fazer configurações automaticamente, ele funcionou normalmente, porem ao fazer um teste utilizando uma pasta que estava com espaço no seu nome ele parou de funcionar, coloquei na variável "" e voltou ao normal.

Porem eu quero evitar qualquer problema futuro e fiz uma pasta com alguns caracteres que podem dar problema, o nome da pasta ficou deste jeito:

> Nova - pasta_ ação';#@$%¬&()+-.,{}][~~~~

Este é o meu ultimo teste:

```
SET mypath="%~dp0"
cd %mypath%
```

Se eu abri o cmd acessando a pasta como administrador ou com usuário normal funciona normalmente, mas se utilizo o explore clico duas vezes funciona com o usuário normal mas não como administrador, assim que abre como administrador o script fecha imediatamente.

Meu script deve rodar como administrador então isso se tornou um problema, claro que este problema só ocorre nesta pasta com o nome cheio de caracteres especiais.

Como executar um script sem me preocupar com caracteres especiais?

Gravei um vídeo para vocês verem o que esta acontecendo.

https://youtu.be/8O_3vHqqTwg

Comment: Já pensou em usar o [PowerShell](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/145926/101)?

Comment: Não, porque eu quero algo que a pessoa só abra e pronto, coloquei ate uma validação no script, se ele abrir com usuário comum aparece uma mensagem para executar como administrador, se tiver algum jeito de executar o script somente com powershell pra mim tudo bem. Até porque se eu acesso utilizando o cmd como administrador vou ate a pasta e executo o script também funciona.

Comment: Creio que só se você criar um executável de verdade ao invés de usar `.bat`.

Comment: Estou pesquisando como fazer um instalador, mas mesmo assim eu queria saber como fazer para trabalhar com qualquer pasta utilizando um batch, porque sempre tenho que criar um batch para alguma coisa, e com esta resposta alem de ajudar a resolver este problema já que o único problema no script é o caminho, me ajudaria bastante em scripts futuros.

Comment: Fiz mais alguns testes, o script independente do conteúdo(Coloquei somente o comando "pause"), se ele estiver dentro da pasta "Nova - pasta_ ação';#@$%¬&()+-.,{}][~~~~" e se for executado como administrador utilizando o windows explorer ele abre não faz nada e fecha.

Comment: Gravei um vídeo para vocês verem o que esta acontecendo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Encontrei uma única forma de resolver seu problema.
eu fiz o meu script e deu certo aqui, mas você pode optar por fazer o seu

você irá fazer uma "casca" pro seu script
com o programa Bat To Convert EXE
eu utilizo muito essa tecnica quando quero compilar um script
para poder edita-lo futuramente.

esse é o script da casca

```
@echo off
call "script.cmd"
```

você vai compila-lo com o programa e marcar a opção "adicionar manifesto de administrador"

a casca estará com privilégio administrativo e em seguida irá chamar o seu script
para dentro.

o script que fiz foi esse aqui.

```
@echo off
echo.>new_file.txt
ping 0 -n 2 >nul
FOR %%c in (new_file.txt) do (set cam="%%~dpc")
echo.%cam%>dir.txt
pause

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%F in (dir.txt) do (set linha=%%F
set linha=!linha:"=!
set mypath=!linha!
set mypath=!mypath:^(=^(!
set mypath=!mypath:^)=^)!
set mypath=!mypath:^¬=^¬!

set mypath=!mypath!
echo.!mypath!
cd !mypath!
pause
)
```