# Como personalizar o reCAPTCHA v2?

Tags: css, google, recaptcha, layout-responsivo

Eu coloquei o reCAPTCHA v2 no meu site, mas tenho problema do tipo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Queria deixar ele responsivo, de forma que ele acompanhe o tamanho dos campos.

Encontrei solução do tipo:

```
transform:scale(0.77);
-webkit-transform:scale(0.77);
transform-origin:0 0;
-webkit-transform-origin:0 0;
```

Mas isso só altera a escala do elemento, o problema de usar desta forma é que ele aumenta a largura e a altura e ainda não consigo fazer desta forma responsiva.

Outra solução é usar o reCAPTCHA v2 invisível, o problema dele é que ele cria uma "aba":

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No canto direito inferior do site, eu tenho um botão flutuante e esta "aba" atrapalha e não posso ocultar esta "aba" por causa dos termos e condições do reCAPTCHA v2.

> You agree to explicitly inform visitors to your site that you have
>   implemented the Invisible reCAPTCHA on your site and that their use of
>   the Invisible reCAPTCHA is subject to the Google Privacy Policy and
>   Terms of Use.

O fator complicador aqui é que ele é um iframe e o seu conteúdo não acompanha as bordas, ou seja, se eu colocar no css por exemplo width: 100% o seu conteúdo não vai ate a borda.

Comment: Passei por esse problema uma vez e encontrei uma pergunta no SO que dizia que isso não é possível: [ReCaptcha API v2 Styling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27713505/recaptcha-api-v2-styling)

Comment: Eu vi, mas ainda tenho esperança, tive um problema com um bat, que ele não executava em uma pasta, fui no fórum da microsoft, aqui e todos falavam que era impossível, ate que depois de um tempo apareceu um cara e me deu uma reposta que fiquei surpreendido: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/240236/como-executar-um-script-sem-me-preocupar-com-caracteres-especiais

Comment: Entendi, deixo meu +1 porque essa pergunta é dúvida de muita gente!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**É realmente necessário deixar o reCAPTCHA responsivo?**

Ao meu ver não é necessário, não se trata de um componente nativo/padrão, para entrar em conformidade com outros inputs, mas sim uma aplicação externa que depende muitas vezes de um estilo padrão.

Até mesmo em termos estéticos, um captcha com a largura 100% em desktop não seria uma coisa tão bonita de se ver.

Existe como deixa-lo em escala compatível com o container sim, segue um exemplo

```js
function scaleCaptcha(elementWidth) {
  // Width of the reCAPTCHA element, in pixels
  var reCaptchaWidth = 300;
  // Get the containing element's width
 var containerWidth = $('.container').width();
  
  // Only scale the reCAPTCHA if it won't fit
  // inside the container
  if(reCaptchaWidth > containerWidth) {
    // Calculate the scale
    var captchaScale = containerWidth / reCaptchaWidth;
    // Apply the transformation
    $('.g-recaptcha').css({
      'transform':'scale('+captchaScale+')'
    });
  }
}

$(function() { 
 
  // Initialize scaling
  scaleCaptcha();
  
  // Update scaling on window resize
  // Uses jQuery throttle plugin to limit strain on the browser
  $(window).resize( $.throttle( 100, scaleCaptcha ) );
  
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  max-width: 250px;
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 20px;
}

.g-recaptcha {
  transform-origin: left top;
  -webkit-transform-origin: left top;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <p>O captcha acompanhou o container de (300 px)</p>  
  <form action="" method="get">
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LcHGhITAAAAABIgEAplK2EWsVFkaE5o0DWUpsIs"></div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Fonte [Codepen](https://codepen.io/dloewen/pen/jbgeZj/)

Comment: Muito bom! Funcionou aqui, precisa cara, o site já esta todo estilizado, e só aquela ponta pra fora quando chega em resolução 320px, e é bom ter isso para projetos futuros.