# Como posso ordenar um resultado no Laravel com um attributo personalizado da minha model?

Tags: php, laravel

A minha tabela real é muito grande, então irei usar este exemplo que encontrei na internet para ficar mais fácil de explicar meu problema ([fonte](http://www.expertphp.in/article/laravel-use-of-accessors-and-mutators-to-format-eloquent-attributes)).

Campos da tabela:

> ```
> first_name
> last_name
> email
> password
> created_at
> updated_at
> ```

No Laravel podemos personalizar nossos campos na model, como por exemplo (assim conseguimos resgatar o nome completo do usuário):

```
function getFullNameAttribute()
{
  return $this->attributes['first_name'] . ' ' . $this->attributes['last_name'];
}
```

Assim ao utilizar a model, eu consigo resgatar o nome completo desta forma:

```
$user = App\User::find(1);
echo $user->full_name;
```

Podemos fazer uma pesquisa desta forma:

```
$users = User::orderBy('name')->get();
```

Mas se eu tentar fazer uma pesquisa pelo nome completo:

```
$users = User::orderBy('full_name')->get();
```

Eu não vou conseguir, já que ele não vai encontrar o campo 'full_name' no meu banco, então para contornamos isso fazemos o seguinte:

```
$users = User::get()->sortBy('full_name');
return $users;
```

E ai que entra o meu problema, quando você executa o seguinte comando:

```
$users = User::orderBy('name')->limit(3)->get();
```

Ele resgata do banco somente 3 valores, mas se eu executar o seguinte comando:

```
$users = User::get()->sortBy('full_name')->take(3);
```

Ele pega todos os usuários do banco e depois ordena e então pega os 3 valores, ocasionando lentidão, já que ele busca todos os valores para depois fazer o filtro.

Como posso ordenar um resultado no Laravel com um attributo personalizado da minha model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tinha um `datatable` e precisava fazer a sua ordenação, mas existiam alguns campos formatados.

Todos os meus campos formatados eu deixei com o padrão "nome_campo_formatted", ou seja, era sempre o nome original mais o "_formatted" no final.

O que fiz para resolver este problema, criei o seguinte método

```
private function filterField($column)
{
    return str_replace(
        '_formatted',
        '',
        $column
    );
}
```

Assim quando fosse ordenar, ao invés de utilizar "nome_campo_formatted" eu utilizava "nome_campo" e se caso entrasse um campo que não fosse formatado a função não substituiria nada e funcionária da mesma forma.

Answer (score 1):

Resposta curta: Não tem jeito.

O banco só entende o que realmente está no banco.

O único jeito é replicar a funcionalidade do atributo customizado na sua query. No  seu caso, você precisa  usar o `CONCAT` do SQL. E pra usar essas funções, você precisa usar `orderByRaw`.

Seria isso:

```
User::orderByRaw("CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name)")->limit(3)->get();
```

Comment: Eu coloquei apenas como exemplo este código, para ficar mais simples de explicar, mas o campo ao qual eu quero fazer esta comparação tem diversos teste, e o código ficaria gigantesco se fosse fazer desta forma.

Comment: Pois então,  não tem como você passar uma propriedade computada pelo Eloquent pra sua query.

Comment: O jeito vai ser trazer todos os registros e filtrar depois. Mas talvez há alguma coisa mais óbvia na tabela que te permite reduzir a quantidade de registros que vc vai ter que trazer antes de rodar os filtros.

Comment: Muito obrigado, mas vou esperar mais um pouco, quem sabe alguém saiba a resposta.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45586280/ordering-by-a-custom-attribute-in-laravel-5-model

Comment: Eu vi este link, a solução que ele deu e exatamente como descrevi na pergunta, ele pega da collection.

Comment: Pois é, coloquei o link pra reforçar que é impossível fazer o que você tá tentando fazer.

Comment: De qualquer forma eu vou esperar, porque já tive experiências aqui no stack de perguntas "impossíveis" e chega alguém e da uma resposta genial, como esta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/240236/como-executar-um-script-sem-me-preocupar-com-caracteres-especiais

Comment: Bom, espero que alguém consiga encontrar essa solução pra você :)

Answer (score 0):

Não pode utilizar um dado computado na `SQL` do seu banco de dados, mas, se pode utilizar duas vezes o `orderBy` e solucionar esse problema da seguinte forma:

```
$users = User::orderBy('first_name')
              ->orderBy('last_name')
              ->limit(3)
              ->get();
```

uma outra forma é criar uma visão com `concat` juntando as duas informações e fazer uma busca simples pelo `Database`do `Laravel`, ***exemplo***:

`View`

```
CREATE  
    VIEW `database`.`view_usuario` 
    AS
    SELECT id, CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) full_name FROM usuario
```

`Laravel`

```
\DB::select('SELECT * FROM view_usuario ORDER BY full_name limit 3');
```

ou

```
\DB::table('view_usuario')->orderBy('full_name')->limit(3)->get();
```